# HP Chromebook customization

Tags: google-chrome-os

Is there a way to make my HP Chromebook compatible with Windows 10 or read the memory stick that has files from my other laptop?
Just plugging it in doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

When you connect an external storage device to a Chromebook

Click the Launcher button in the lower-left corner of your Chromebook's display and then click the Files app. If you don't see it listed, it means you haven't used it recently and will need to click All Apps and find the Files app listed among all of your Chromebook's apps.

[image]

With the Files window opened, in the left panel you should see your external drive listed directly below the Downloads folder. Just as you can in Windows Explorer on a PC or Finder on a Mac, you can view the drive's folders and files here. Just double click a file to open it.

[image]

If you want to move a file from an external drive to your Chromebook, you have two options: drag and drop or copy and paste.

```
Supported file types
According to Google, these are the types of files Chrome OS supports:

Microsoft Office files: .doc, .docx, .xls, .xlsx, .ppt (read-only), .pptx (read-only).
Media: .3gp, .avi, .mov, .mp4, .m4v, .m4a, .mp3, .mkv, .ogv, .ogm, .ogg, .oga, .webm, .wav
Images: .bmp, .gif, .jpg, .jpeg, .png, .webp
Compressed files: .zip, .rar
Other: .txt, .pdf (read-only)
```

[Source](https://www.cnet.com/how-to/how-to-use-an-external-drive-with-a-chromebook/)